# Use cache in auth middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to write own auth  route middleware to use user cache. If I will simple check with cache in DB user then I see

`Call to a member function setCookie() on null`

I should use UserProvider probably. But then I don't use cache.

Does it any way to return same result like original auth but set cache inside?

My current code is:

```
<?php
namespace Sakuicms\Auth\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;


class Authenticate
{
    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
      $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    protected function getName()
    {
      return 'login_'.config('auth.defaults.guard').'_'.sha1('Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard');
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
      $id = session($this->getName());
      if($id>0){
        $model = config('auth.providers.users.model');
        return \Cache::rememberForever('db.users.'.$id, function() use($model,$id){
          return $model::select(['id'])->where('id',$id)->first();
        });
      }
      throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', $guards);
      return $next($request);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
I solve this problem. Of course it was my wrong. I always return not `$next($request)` but clear user object

Below is code which work

```
<?php
namespace Sakuicms\Auth\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Sakuicms\Auth\SessionGuard;

class Authenticate
{
    protected $auth;

    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
      $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    protected function getName()
    {
      return 'login_'.config('auth.defaults.guard').'_'.sha1('Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard');
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
      $this->authenticate($guards);
      return $next($request);
    }

    protected function authenticate(array $guards)
    {
      if(empty($guards)){
        $id = session($this->getName());
        if($id>0){
          $model = config('auth.providers.users.model');
          return \Cache::rememberForever('db.users.'.$id, function() use($model,$id){
            return $model::select(['id'])->where('id',$id)->first();
          });
        }
      }

      foreach ($guards as $guard) {
          if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
              return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
          }
      }

      throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', $guards);
    }

}
```

Probably exists better/more elegant solution but for now it's ok for me. I'll refactor it in next stage.